# Comparing nodes of a list with a string array

Tags: c, string, linked-list

If i have an **array** that contains some char such as `[a,b,c]` and i have another **array** that contains the respective frequency of each char such as `[2,1,1]`. I would like to now go through a **linked list** which has nodes which have some string to see if they also have the chars i have in my original array with same frequency.

My approach

I was thinking i need

One loop that will start at `index 0` of original array and another loop inside that will check all nodes for that string and if my temp pointer hits null it means all of them have it and if not then they don't and i move on to the next one. However i am not sure how to quite implement this approach as i am very new to c and also i was wondering is it possible to do this in `O(N)` TIME as my approach would be O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Sample Output: i apologize for the confusion 
so if you have 3 nodes and each has a char array containing `"nba" "tba" "rba"` 
the output should then return `b a`  . since both them appear equal number of times in each node.

Comment: Can u give me example for "some string"  which is mentioned like nodes which have some string. So, just give me a string format.

Comment: you have a linked list with nodes which contain strings. ex node 1 has "jay", node 2 has "rab", node 3 has" clay" . and what i would do is take that array list i already have for example [a,b,c] frequency arra[1,2,3] and see that only a is matching. because each string has char a with frequency of 1.

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR does that make it clear? please let me know

Comment: How do u say that "each string has char a with frequency of 1".? How are u linking frequency and character in string.

Comment: @user2733436: In the example, posted in the comments, am I suppose to neglect every string, since none contains characters `b and c` or just because they matching the frequency w.r.t. `a`, I have to count them in(as output). What if a node has string like __"aabtw"__, here neither `a nor b`'s frequency is matching with that of frequency array. What is to be done in this situation? Please elaborate a bit further, on the problem :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw sorry for confusion i have just edited my question does this make it clear? That is the original issue. what i did then is take the char from first node and find frequency of them in the first node and then tried to do matching with the other nodes but it has become O(N^2) :(

Comment: @user2733436: No need to apologize(we all commit mistakes :-))Again, a slight confusion, this new edit, talks about showing the output with respect to the string inside all nodes, whether frequency of a char in a given string of a given node, matches with that of the other string of another node. But not of those arrays in the start. It seems they are useless, with this new edit.

Comment: @nIcEcOw if you can show me an approach that can get the output in O(N) then yeah we don't need those. i am not sure so i took that route....

Comment: @nIcEcOw is it possible to solve in O(N) ?

Comment: @user2733436: That is what I am thinking too, but seems like if I am suppose to traverse the linked list and then traverse over a string in each node, O(n^2) is what will come, as already stated in the answer. But will think about this in coming days as well :-)

Comment: appreciate it @nIcEcOw, will leave answer box open till next week

Comment: @user2733436: Seems to me O(n^2), is the best so far, in my knowledge, for this task :-) But, I am still thinking :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you start both your char array and freqarray at index 0 and then check all the nodes for strings matching the same frequency of a character . I presume you use some kind of function to return frequency of particular char in a string .
Also your problem requires you to go through all of the nodes hence O(N^2) is implied.